# Solve PDE subject to two conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the following PDE for $u(x, y)$

$u_x + 2√yu_y = 0$

which is defined for $y>0$

Solve the PDE in the domain $Ω$ = {$(x, y) : x > 0, y > 0$} subject to the condition $u(x, 0) = f(x)$ and  $u(0, y) = g(y)$ for
some given functions $f$ and $g$

Ok, so I have found the characteristic curves to be described by

$x −√y = c_1$

I have asked a previous question which was similar, but had only one condition and managed to find the correct answer. I am having problems now that there are 2 conditions and could use some guidance on how to tackle this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method of characteristics leads to the general solution of the PDE, with any differentiable function $F$ :
$$u(x,y)=F(x-\sqrt{y})$$
First condition, in $x>0$ :

$u(x,0)=f(x)=F(x-0) \quad\to\quad F(X)=f(X) \quad\text{in domain }\quad X>0$

Hence with $X=x-\sqrt{y}$ , the solution of the PDE according to the first condition is :

$$u(x,y)=f(x-\sqrt{y})\quad\text{in domain }\quad x-\sqrt{y}>0$$

Second condition, in $y>0$ :

$u(0,y)=g(y)=F(0-\sqrt{y}) \quad\to\quad F(-\sqrt{y})=g(y)\quad\text{in domain  }y>0 $

With $X=-\sqrt{y}\quad$ :   $\quad F(X)=g(X^2)\quad\text{in domain  }X<0$

Hence with $X=x-\sqrt{y}$ , the solution of the PDE according to the second condition is :
$$u(x,y)=g\left((x-\sqrt{y})^2\right)\quad\text{in domain }\quad x-\sqrt{y}<0$$

The solution of the PDE in domain $(x>0\:,\:y>0)$according to the tw0 conditions is :
$$u(x,y)=\begin{cases}
f(x-\sqrt{y}) &\text{if}&  x>\sqrt{y}\\
g\left((x-\sqrt{y})^2\right) &\text{if}&   x<\sqrt{y}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks for the clear solution. I managed to get most of the way but I wasn't confident enough to commit that I had it correct. Thank you!